# How to add dynamic sql column using Linq at runtime

Tags: linq

I have a linq sql class i.e."Customer". I want to implement the features like User Defined Fields. Can you please tell me how can I create dynamic column into this class? How can I access this column from Customer object?

Comment: The whole point of LINQ to SQL is compile-time type-safety.  You need to use SQL directly.

Comment: Does each Customer have it's own Customer Table. If so, you have a mess, if not, you have a different sort of mess. NoSql store would be a better way to go, especially if you want to avoid an EAV design, which would be about your only "sensible" SQl option

Comment: @SLaks : Do you have any other option except SQL directly?